# How to use Google Code

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-code

I use openlike ([openlike.org](http://openlike.org)) but the site seems to be temporarily down.  I would normally use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlike.org/v1/openlike.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">OPENLIKE.Widget()</script>
```

But that isn't working.  I've found the project on google code, I was wondering how I implement exactly the same thing, but from Google?  Is Google code completely different from the google cdn?  I.e. I can't just change the URL of that javascript file?

Google code project: [http://code.google.com/p/openlike/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fv1%253Fstate%253Dclosed](http://code.google.com/p/openlike/source/browse/#svn/trunk/v1%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Thanks for any help,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link posted, if you click on "openlike.js" and then "View raw file" you'll get exactly that:

http://openlike.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/v1/openlike.js

You can certainly link to this file. Here's what I tried and it worked fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlike.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/v1/openlike.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    console.log(OPENLIKE);
</script>
```

I don't know enough about google code and svn to tell you if that file will be there forever and won't change. I doubt that it's intended to be used a CDN. But it's probably good enough to use while openlike.org is down temporarily.

Comment: Agreed on the temporary solution! Thanks for the tips